# Container-VM Image with GPD Volumes fails with "Failed to get GCE Cloud Provider. plugin.host.GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead"

Tags: containers, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-container-os

I currently try to switch from the "Container-Optimized Google Compute Engine Images" (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms) to the "Container-VM" Image (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/vm-image/#overview). In my containers.yaml, I define a volume and a container using the volume.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: workhorse
spec:
  containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: postgres:9.5
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  volumes:
    - name: postgres-storage
      gcePersistentDisk:
        pdName: disk-name
        fsType: ext4
```

This setup worked fine with the "Container-Optimized Google Compute Engine Images", however fails with the "Container-VM". In the logs, I can see the following error:

```
May 24 18:33:43 battleship kubelet[629]: E0524 18:33:43.405470 629 gce_util.go:176]
Error getting GCECloudProvider while detaching PD "disk-name":
Failed to get GCE Cloud Provider. plugin.host.GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead
```

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens only when `kubelet` is run without the `--cloud-provider=gce` flag. The problem, unless is something different, is dependant on how GCP is launching Container-VMs.

Please contact with google cloud platform guys.

*Note if this happens to you when using GCE:* Add `--cloud-provider=gce` flag to `kubelet` in all your workers. This only applies to 1.2 cluster versions because, if i'm not wrong, there is an ongoing attach/detach design targeted for 1.3 clusters <strike>which will move this business logic out of `kubelet`</strike>.

In case someone is interested in the attach/detach redesign here it is its corresponding github issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20262

Comment: How can I add ```--cloud-provider=gce``` flag to ```kubelet```.Please help Iam a beginner.I have the same issue.