# Where is configured the "slow" storage class in a Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

A PersistentVolumeClaim is successfully bound to PersistentVolume using the "slow" storage class but I can't see it inside any namespace. Is this something like a built-in or [provisioner](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) related configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> but I can't see it inside any namespace

Because `StorageClass` resources aren’t namespaced.

> Is this something like a built-in or provisioner-related configuration?

Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56441400/3098330