# AttachVolume.NewAttacher failed for volume: Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider with error <nil>

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have two VM Instance on GCE with kubernetes self install (using the following https://medium.com/edureka/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-5cd1f770c9e4).

I'm trying to create volume and use it in my pods.

I have been created the following disk:

```
gcloud compute disks create --type=pd-ssd --size=10GB manual-disk-1
```

And create the following yaml files

pv_manual.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: manually-created-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: manual-disk-1
```

pvc_manual.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mypvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: sleppypod
spec:
   volumes:
     - name: data
       persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: mypvc
   containers:
     - name: sleppycontainer
       image: gcr.op/google_containers/busybox
       command:
         - sleep
         - "5000"
       volumeMounts:
         - name: data
           mountPath: /data
           readOnly: false
```

And when I'm  trying to create the pod the pode get status `ContainerCreating` and on `kubectl get events` I see:

> 7s          Warning   FailedAttachVolume                   AttachVolume.NewAttacher failed for volume : Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider with error

I run my  two instances using ServiceAccount with compute instance admin role (according [Kubernetes: Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider with error <nil>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100219/kubernetes-failed-to-get-gce-gcecloudprovider-with-error-nil)) and  my `kubelet` running  with `--cloud-provider=gce`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you add the output of `kubectl get sc` ?

Comment: No resources found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a storageclass

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  fstype: ext4
  replication-type: none
```

For GCE details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#gce-pd)

You can also follow GCE documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/how-to/default-storage-class#deploy_storage_system)

Comment: I need to create only storageclass? or should I create also disk, pv, pvc? Can you show me  please example of pod.yaml file that use this storageclass please?

Comment: you need storageclass first. then this will be used when pv will be created. you don't need to create disk. create storageclass, pv, pvc

Comment: I create storageclass and  then pvc but  when i run kubectl get pvc the pvc on pending status

Comment: did you create pod with the pvc?

Comment: Now It's  working, This storage can accessible from master also?If so, how?

Comment: The disk mounted to that node where the pod is scheduled. If you use tolleration to schedule your pod on master than the volume will be mounted on master node