# What Persistent Volume storage solutions I can use when I run my Kubernetes cluster on GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, persistent-storage

I have deployed  my Kubernetes cluster on GCP Compute Engines and having 3 Master Nodes and 3 Worker Nodes (It's not a GKE Cluster). Can anybody suggest me what storage options I can use for my cluster? If I create a virtual disk on GCP, can I use that disk as a persistent storage?

Comment: This may help you: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes

Comment: What are your requirement? Do you need to read and write concurrently on the same storage?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I'm having few pods, I need to store each pod's data separately in in the disk, separated by each other. What option you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GCE Persistent Disk Storage Class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#gce-pd).

Here is how you create the storage class:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
```

Then you do the following to create the PV & PVC and to attach to your pod.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: gce-claim
spec:
 accessModes:
   - ReadWriteOnce
 storageClassName: ssd
 resources:
   requests:
     storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: webserver-pd
spec:
 containers:
 - image: httpd
   name: webserver
   volumeMounts:
   - mountPath: /data
     name: dynamic-volume
 volumes:
 - name: dynamic-volume
   persistentVolumeClaim:
     claimName: gce-claim
```

Example taken from [this blog post](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-storage-101)

Comment: if I proceed with this solution, do I need to edit the kubernetes config? Specifying the cloud provider or something?

Comment: @Dusty yeah, I think you have to configure IAM for the each instance (basically setup a service account with sufficient storage permissions).. also since you're working outside GKE, you should configure `cloud-provider` to `GCE` in configs

Comment: where exactly should I provide cloud-provider parameter?

Comment: Try following [this commit diff](https://github.com/eldorplus/kubernetes-the-hard-way/commit/ecf26a1100f5e95b6c7e44c01a65ef8c624f37f4), maybe? (I don't have experience doing this configuration, sorry)

Comment: it's working now. Since I'm running my cluster outside from GKE, we need to specifically provide --cloud-provider=gce parameter in api and contoller-manager conf file. And restarted kubelet. BTW thanks for your support.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it finally has worked out! we all have learned something in the process :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of provisioning Persistent Volumes: `Static Provisioning` and `Dynamic Provisioning`.
I will briefly describe each of these types.

#### [Static Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#static)

Using this approach you need to create `Disk`, `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` manually.
I've create simple example for you to illustrate how it works.

First I created disk, on GCP we can use `gcloud` command:

```
$ gcloud compute disks create --size 10GB --region europe-west3-c test-disk
NAME       ZONE            SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
test-disk  europe-west3-c  10       pd-standard  READY
```

Next I created `PV` and `PVC` using this manifest files:

```
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce  
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: test-disk # This GCE PD must already exist.
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: claim-test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

After applaying this manifest files, we can check status of `PV` and `PVC`:

```
root@km:~# kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pv-test   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/claim-test                           12m

NAME                               STATUS   VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/claim-test   Bound    pv-test   10Gi       RWO                           12m
```

Finally I used above claim as volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx"
        name: vol-test
  volumes:
    - name: vol-test
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: claim-test
```

We can inspect created `Pod` to check if it works as expected:

```
root@km:~# kubectl exec -it web -- bash
root@web:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdb        9.8G   37M  9.8G   1% /usr/share/nginx
...
```

#### [Dynamic Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic)

In this case volume is provisioned automatically when application requires it.
First you need to create `StorageClass` object to define a provisioner such e.g. `kubernetes.io/gce-pd`.
We don't need to create `PersistenVolume` anymore, it's created automatically by `StorageClass` for us.
I've also created simple example for you to illustrate how it works.

First I created `StorageClass` as default storage class:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  fstype: ext4
```

And then `PVC` (the same as in the previous example) - but in this case `PV` was created automatically:

```
root@km:~# kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pvc-8dcd69f1-7081-45a7-8424-cc02e61a4976   10Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound    default/claim-test   standard                3m10s

NAME                               STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/claim-test   Bound    pvc-8dcd69f1-7081-45a7-8424-cc02e61a4976   10Gi       RWO            standard       3m12s
```

In more advanced cases it may be useful to create multiple `StorageClasses` with differnet [persistent disks types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#disk-types).

Comment: I followed the same steps which you have mentioned in Dynamic Provisioning. But when I check the status of PVC, it's in pending state. Below is the error which I get.

Comment: Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ssd": Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider with error <nil>

Comment: @Dusty you probably didn't configure GCE as cloud provider. Please follow steps from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50364756/14801225)

Comment: there they have edited the /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf file. But when I check my cluster, I don't have a file in this location. Please help

Comment: Did you deploy k8s using `kubeadm` ?
Which Linux distribution do you use ?

Comment: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/01-prerequisites.md

Comment: Followed the above steps and deployed

Comment: I'm struggling where to put the cloud provider flag

Comment: Do you have `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service` file ?
Try to add `--cloud-provider=gce` at the end of `ExecStart` statement.
Probably you also need to add `--cloud-provider=gce` to `/etc/systemd/system/kube-controller-manager.service` to `ExecStart`. And then restart `kubelet` and `kube-controller-manager` services.

Comment: I have add the --cloud-provider=gce in /etc/systemd/system/kube-apiserver.service and /etc/systemd/system/kube-controller-manager.service in each controller. And also I added --cloud-provider=gce in /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service in each worker. Eventually in each worker I executed {
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  sudo systemctl enable containerd kubelet kube-proxy
  sudo systemctl start containerd kubelet kube-proxy
}

Comment: And also in each controller I executed {
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  sudo systemctl enable kube-apiserver kube-controller-manager kube-scheduler
  sudo systemctl start kube-apiserver kube-controller-manager kube-scheduler
} after adding the --cloud-provider

Comment: Still issue exists. What else I can do?

Comment: it's working now. Since I'm running my cluster outside from GKE, we need to specifically provide --cloud-provider=gce parameter in api and contoller-manager conf file. And restarted kubelet. BTW thanks for your support.